# Text messaging using a-frame

Tags: aframe, aframe-networked

I want to add a text chat system in a-frame. I'm using networked a-frame as connectivity can be anything possible with that or I've to do using some other tech.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [simple API to send custom messages](https://github.com/networked-aframe/networked-aframe#sending-custom-messages) with the network layer that is already setup:

```
// subscribe to custom data
NAF.connection.subscribeToDataChannel(dataType, (senderId, dataType, data, targetId) => {})

// send custom data
NAF.connection.broadcastData(dataType, data)
```

So sending an chat message is as simple as:

```
const btn = document.querySelector("button");      // SEND btn
const input = document.querySelector("input");     // input field with the text
const log = document.querySelector("#messages")    // message log

// when you want to send a message
btn.addEventListener("click", evt => {
  // log your own messages
  messages.innerHTML += NAF.clientId + ": " + input.value + '<br>'
  // broadcast the text as some unique dataType (like "chat")
  NAF.connection.broadcastData("chat", {txt: input.value}) 
})

// when a "chat" type message arrives
NAF.connection.subscribeToDataChannel("chat", (senderId, dataType, data, targetId) => {
  // append the data.txt to the message log
  messages.innerHTML += senderId + ": " + data.txt + '<br>'
})
```

Check it out [in this glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/gftruj-aframenetworked-chat?path=public%2Findex.html%3A153%3A51):

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. You solved my problem completely. This solution helps me a lot. Think you're much experienced in A-frame and you're a great inspiration for me.

Comment: Glad I could help. If You think the answer is clear feel free to mark it :)

Comment: Sure, I forgot to do that.

Comment: I want to add a name rather than a client Id.  Can you please help me with this?

Comment: sure, I'll check it out later today

Comment: Ok, thanks for that, I'm eagerly waiting for learning new things about this.